# What does semi transparent questions mean?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

Sometimes I see questions in half transparent state.

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: @devnull - Nope. Deleted questions are not listed in first place. It means the question's tag is in your ignored tags.

Comment: Interesting questions tag are highlighted; ignored questions are dimmed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Favorite Tags* -->  Questions with Favorite tags become highlighted.

*Ignored Tags* --> Questions with Ignored tags are shown faded; they are still visible but less prominent.

And if you have a question which has both favourite and ignored tags then its both highlightened and faded out (or as you said semi -transparent.)

Comment: BTW If checked in your profile, then questions containing ignored tags get removed from the list.